# Getting the cell side in Ocean?

Tags: ocean

How do you get access to the cell sides (DX,DY,DZ) from a grid model that is loaded in Petrel?

I can get the cell volume corresponding to a particular index, but how can I get the cell side in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Grid` method `GetCellCorners(Index3, CellCorner[])` to get cell point corners' coordinates (you will have 8 of them for each cell), and then compute cell sides. But be aware that grid cells are not necessarily rectangular boxes, so, for example, you may have 4 different DZs in one cell.